# Return value doesn't work in Python 3

Tags: python, return

It seems like I can't pass a value from a function to another even though I have put a `return` statement in the 1st function.

This is my code:

```
price=0
TotalPrice=0

def SumPrice(price,TotalPrice):
    if cup_cone=="cup":
        price=(price+(mass/10)*0.59)*TotalSet
    else:
        if cone_size=="small":
            price=(price+2)*TotalSet
        else:
            if cone_size=="medium":
                price=(price+3)*TotalSet
            else:
                price=(price+4)*TotalSet

    if Member_Ans=="yes":
        TotalPrice=TotalPrice+price*0.90

    print(price,TotalPrice)
    return (price)
    return (TotalPrice)

def PrintDetails(price,TotalPrice,Balance):
    SumPrice(price,TotalPrice)
    if Member_Ans=="yes":
        print("Member ID: ", loginID, " (" , Username, ")")

    for element in range (len(UserFlavor)):
        print (UserFlavor[element], "--- ", UserFlavorPercentage[element], "%")

    print ("Total set = ", TotalSet)
    print ("Total price = RM %.2f" % (price))
    if Member_Ans=="yes":
        print ("Price after 10% discount = RM %.2f" %  (TotalPrice))

    while True:
        Payment=int(input("Please enter your payment: "))
        if Payment<TotalPrice:
            print("Not enough payment.")
        if Payment >= TotalPrice:
            break

    Balance=Balance+(Payment-TotalPrice)
    print(Balance)

PrintDetails(price,TotalPrice,Balance)
```

When I try to print the `price` and `TotalPrice`, it prints `0`, why?

Comment: You can't return twice. Your function ends with the first return statement that is reached.

Comment: I've changed to return "price" only, but it still prints "0".How to solve it?

Comment: @Jess you have to describe exactly the problem you are having, the input and expected output for us to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `return` statement of first function is not reachable! btw try to not use global variables in your code, instead access return values of your first function.

```
def SumPrice():
    price = 0
    TotalPrice = 0
    if cup_cone=="cup":
        price=(price+(mass/10)*0.59)*TotalSet
    else:
        if cone_size=="small":
            price=(price+2)*TotalSet
        else:
            if cone_size=="medium":
                price=(price+3)*TotalSet
            else:
                price=(price+4)*TotalSet

    if Member_Ans=="yes":
        TotalPrice=TotalPrice+price*0.90

    return price, TotalPrice

def PrintDetails():
    price, TotalPrice = SumPrice()
    if Member_Ans=="yes":
        print("Member ID: ", loginID, " (" , Username, ")")

    for element in range (len(UserFlavor)):
        print (UserFlavor[element], "--- ", UserFlavorPercentage[element], "%")

    print ("Total set = ", TotalSet)
    print ("Total price = RM %.2f" % (price))
    if Member_Ans=="yes":
        print ("Price after 10%% discount = RM %.2f" %  (TotalPrice))

    while True:
        Payment=int(input("Please enter your payment: "))
        if Payment<TotalPrice:
            print("Not enough payment.")
        if Payment >= TotalPrice:
            break

    Balance=Balance+(Payment-TotalPrice)
    print(Balance)

PrintDetails()
```

Comment: I removed the global variables, but it results in error (NameError: name 'price' is not defined)

Comment: @Jess The indent of this line ```PrintDetails(price,TotalPrice,Balance)```was incorrect, now try the code.

Comment: I added after your remind, but it still pops up the same error

Comment: @Jess I updated the code, you don't need pass variables to your ```PrintDetails``` function since it's getting ```price``` and ```TotalPrice``` values from ```SumPrice``` function. Also i assume that you defined ```cup_cone``` , ```Member_Ans``` and ```cone_size ``` somewhere in your code.

Comment: I follow all the codes that u have changed for me, now another error occured. UnboundLocalError: local variable 'price' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Jess Where it happens?

Comment: I solved it! Thanks so much for your help!!!  But now i face another problem, in this line print ("Price after 10% discount = RM %.2f" %  (TotalPrice)) , it shows 'TypeError: not enough arguments for format string', can you help me?

Comment: @Jess Great. Your error's because of your ```10%``` string. Python uses the ```%``` character for string formatting. instead use ```10%%``` , I updated the code.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `return` twice, which is not allowed (your function will end as soon as it reaches the 1st `return` statement, making the other one useless).
You can, however, return both values in one statement:

```
return (price, TotalPrice)
```

And then assign the value to a tuple or anything else you would like:

```
my_tuple = SumPrice(a, b)
```

or

```
var1, var2 = SumPrice(a, b)
```

Comment: Great, Used of my answer and down voted for my post?

Comment: If you implied that I copied your answer then you must be joking since I answered 2 minutes before.